# advertise data using Bluetooth in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently making an app in flutter. In that app I need to advertise data using bluetooth. Currently I am using `flutter_ble_peripheral` to advertise data and it is working. Now I want to advertise the data from iphone, however `flutter_ble_peripheral` currently supports adverting data only from android. I have read the documentation of other packages and I am unable to find anything mentioned about advertising manufacturer data. Can someone suggest me any good alternative for `flutter_ble_peripheral` or suggest me any other way to advertise data from both android and iphone.

Comment: Just search for bluetooth on https://pub.dev

Comment: do you think i don't know that, if you don't know answer don't comment @Andrej